# How can I add a padding before and after a label that overlaps the top border of an input field?

Tags: html, css, input

I am trying to create input fields that look like this [image: 1]

which is easy enough because I can add a white background to the label with some padding. The problem is when the field appears on a non-white background like this

[image: 2]

Is there any way to accomplish this with a transparent background on the label?

https://jsfiddle.net/jgu61qaq/

```
<div class="floating-label bg-white">
  <label>Label</label>
  <input type="text" value="Something">
</div>

<div class="floating-label bg-gray">
  <label>Label</label>
  <input type="text" value="Something">
</div>

<style>
.floating-label {
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.bg-white {
  background: #fff;
}

.bg-gray {
  background: #eee;
}

input {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

label {
  font-size: 11px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 25px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: If you give the label a transparent background then the input's border will show through.

Comment: @j08691 Yes, that's exactly my issue. I need to find a way to keep it transparent but have not have the border show behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?:

```
label {
  position: relative;
  top: -16px;
  left: 46px;
  z-index: 0;
}
label:before {
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jgu61qaq/3/

I used :before selector to create a white 50% height of label element to hide the border

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
    background-color:#ececec;
}

fieldset{
    padding: 0;
    width: 0;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

fieldset input{
    border:none;
    margin-top:-10px;
    height:25px; 
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

```html
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Lorem Ipsum:</legend>
  <input type="text">
 </fieldset>
```